# How can I "temporary" store some values from a decoded JSON table?

Tags: php, temporary

I am constructing a function that is making a call with API to db and returns me JSON data. The json contains orders and I have already decoded them in php array. Every order has properties such as "product_id" and "quantity". I want to temporarily store the "quantity" property somewhere because I need to sum all the products with the same product_id. Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: You already have them temporarily stored in a php array surely?

Comment: Are you asking how to store them between requests or during the same request?

Comment: Why not just make a function that will give you the result you want? Since you got everything stored in a db, you could just do a simple query to get that result.

Comment: Sessions or cookies can be used to store the data temporarily.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't want to do it with a query to the db because I want to do it with API. It's important to do it this way for the safety of the data. I am the only one who has the API key.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes i am sure.

Comment: _"It's important to do it this way for the safety of the data"_ - That makes no sense. You just said that you're making a API function to get the data you're going to use for the calculation, so do another API function that gives you the summed up data as well? Either way, you still need to give us way more info before we can give some constructive suggestions. Is it per request? Per user session? Globally for all users?

Comment: @phpfresher do you have a more specific suggestion? or a tutorial?

Comment: @TasosSeit... Something like `$_SESSION["session_name"] = "YOUR DATA HERE";`.. and later access that data using `$_SESSION["session_name"]`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0RwsPsJ

This array is constructed manually and dynamically call the properties from the db. I would like to summarize the quantities of the same products.

Comment: It appears [your question was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54042699/1155833). Remember that SO is not a coding service. If an answer makes it possible for you to fix your specific implementation, that's the answer. Mark it as such. Before your next question, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in a bit of a hurry, but wanted to see if I could help you out.

```
$quantities = [];

//Loop through all the orders
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    //Loop through the orderrows
    foreach ($order->getOrderRows() as $orderRow) {
        if (array_key_exists($orderRow->getProductName(), $quantities)) {
            //The product is already in the quantities array, so the quantity of this orderrow is added to the total
            $quantities[$orderRow->getProductName()] =
                ($quantities[$orderRow->getProductName()] + (int) $orderRow->getItemQuantity());
        } else {
            //If this is the first time the product is encountered add the product and its quantity to the quantities array
            $quantities[$orderRow->getProductName()] = (int) $orderRow->getItemQuantity();
        }
    }
}
```

This is going to have the following result, showing you the product names along with their quantities:

```
$quantities = [
    'foo' => 12,
    'bar' => 3,
];
```

Comment: If it solved your issue, could you mark it as solved?

Comment: no it's not but it helped a lot, I can't vote for your answer, because of low reputation.

Comment: The code I provided answers the question. You wanted to "sum all the products with the same product_id", which can be done by using the code above. If there is something else you need to do with this data now, please make a new question regarding what else you need and mark this question as solved.

Answer (score -2):

You may use the session variable to store these values.

Comment: What if the list is massive or/and if the OP is executing the script from CLI?

Comment: than simple file handling is better option. store the data inside a text file.

Comment: If it is a lot of data, it would be better to store it in a database (or simply just do a query to the DB directly to get the info). The point is, since the OP haven't given us nearly enough information, any suggestions/answers are just wild guesses.